# Python doctest fails on 0.0 != -0.0--what gives?

Tags: python

Given the following code:

```
def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """
      >>> slope(5, 3, 4, 2)
      1.0
      >>> slope(1, 2, 3, 2)
      0.0
      >>> slope(1, 2, 3, 3)
      0.5
      >>> slope(2, 4, 1, 2)
      2.0
    """
    xa = float (x1)
    xb = float (x2)
    ya = float (y1)
    yb = float (y2)
    return (ya-yb)/(xa-xb)

if name_ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The second doctest fails:

```
Failed example:
    slope(1, 2, 3, 2)
Expected:
    0.0
Got:
    -0.0
```

However, we all know that -0.0 == 0.0. Is doctest doing a string comparison to check results here? Why does the second test fail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It fails because [doctest](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/doctest.html) does *string comparison*. It merely checks whether the output is identical to what would have been outputted if the code had been executed at the Python interactive interpreter:

```
>>> 0 / -2
-0.0
```

**Edit:**: The link [referenced](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#doctest.OutputChecker.check_output) by [Daniel Lew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60261/daniel-lew) below gives some more hints about how this works, and how you may be able to influence this behaviour.

Comment: Reference link: http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#doctest.OutputChecker.check_output